# Wowza Stream not Live, why?

Tags: stream, video-streaming, rtmp, live-streaming, wowza

i am sending live rtmp stream to wowza server with a live application config but everytime i connect to the stream for watching the live stream, its start from the beginning of the stream. I can see wowza is creating bigger and bigger file in /content directory and this file will everytime be played from the beginning.

How can i say wowza to send it live, like send the last 10 seconds of the file?

Best regards,

Chris

Comment: -1 for providing zero details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these instructions to create a live stream and broadcasting it

Go to the Wowza Media Server Directory. Probably it is /usr/local/WowzaMediaServer

cd applications;mkdir live

Here live is your application name

cd ../conf;mkdir live;cp Application.xml live/

Now edit the Application.xml file

cd live;vim Application.xml

Change the stream type default to live

live

set HTTPStreamers

cupertinostreaming,smoothstreaming,sanjosestreaming

set LiveStreamPacketizers to

cupertinostreamingpacketizer, smoothstreamingpacketizer, sanjosestreamingpacketizer

set Playmethod

none

Now go to your browser and open the player

file:///usr/local/WowzaMediaServer/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/client/live.html

Server : rtmp://;1935/live
Stream :

Note * : For live streaming you have to use an encoder ( Adobe Flash media Live Encoder , etc )

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have more luck asking this question on the [Wowza forums](http://www.wowza.com/forums/), where their support team regularly addresses these questions.  You'll need to provide more information:

- What is your input (camera, flash media encoder, file)?
- Can you stream VOD?
- A large file building in the content directory sounds like you may be recording the stream.  Do you have any add-ons such as the live stream recorder installed?
- What url are you using to connect?

Comment: I have asked the ppls in the wowza forum. I just put my application.xml in the wrong directory, it should be {wowza dir}/conf/live/application.xml not {wowza dir}/applications/live/application.xml ... now its running fine. thx

Answer (score 1):

Well that answer is simple. You set the wrong stream type in the config.

I guess you set rtp-live-record instead of rtp-live that should fix it.

Kind Regards, Sui